# Hibernate 4.1 Count Projection Type Mismatch (Long/Integer) using Result Transformer

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have an entity bean `FooEntity` and DAO method to get row counts grouped by a property on that entity, encapsulated in a view model bean `FooCount`.

```
public List<FooCount> groupByFoo() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(FooEntity.class)
        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("foo"), "foo")
            .add(Projections.count("foo"), "count")
        ).setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FooCount.class))  
        .list();
}

public class FooCount {
    private String foo;
    private Integer count; // <-- this is the problem
    // getters/setters...
}
```

Running this gives an exception, since `Projections.count()` yields a `Long` instead of an `Integer`.

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of FooCount.count
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:119)
--snip--
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

It works if I change `count` to a `Long` but I would prefer not to change the view model class as it is used is various other places.

Can I either make `Projections.count()` return an `Integer` somehow *or* make the result transformer convert from `Long` to `Integer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast it to Integer using a SQL projection:

```
.setProjection( Projections.sqlProjection(
    "Cast(Count(foo) as Integer) count",
    new String[]{"count"},
    new Type[]{StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER}
)
```

Comment: Ah brilliant. This is also much better than my current solution as my actual code is more complex than the SSCCE I posted, which this allows me to simplify even further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do the conversion yourself in the attribute's setter method?

Comment: I did try this, but was hoping for a way that didn't involve changing the `FooCount` bean

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the standard mapping for COUNT(*) function in Hibernate is [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). So replacing of Integer can help:

```
public class FooCount {
  private String foo;
  private BigDecimal count; // <-- 

  // getters/setters...
}
```