# Classcast Exception while running Projection count query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate 4.3.1 final version of hibernate.
In the hibernate mapping file i have defined that property as a integer.
For eg: `<property name= "jobNo" type="integer">`

database used is DB2.
In which the jobNo column is defined as `Integer`.
When trying to retrive the count of jobNo using Projection API as:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.count(jobNo));
criteria.uniqueResult();
```

It is returning as `Long`. Ideally, it should be returned as `Integer`.

I am new into this can someone help me on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is returning as Long. Ideally, it should be returned as Integer.

You have not the hand on it. It's handled by your JPA implementation (hibernate here).

If you know that the value returned by the `count` cannot exceed the Integer max value (2147483647), it should not be a problem. You can convert the Long to Integer. If you have doubt, you can check that the Long value doesn't exceed
the Integer max value.
Anyway, I advise you to cast to a `Number` rather than a `Long`, you may avoid surprise if you change the JPA implementation.

```
int jobNo = ((Number)criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

org.hibernate.criterion.Projections.count(String propertyName) always returns Long value like what is returned with HQL. Use Long type in your mapping. If you don't want to change the mapping type then another solution is given at [Hibernate 4.1 Count Projection Type Mismatch (Long/Integer) using Result Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712940/hibernate-4-1-count-projection-type-mismatch-long-integer-using-result-transfo). Hope this helps.